# Failed to download data from FTP server to shiny app in shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

My shiny app needs to download file from ftp, I can download using R console. For example:

**R console:**

`library(curl)`

`setwd("/srv/shiny-server/PowerSeq_app/www")`    `curl_download("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv",destfile="reviews2.csv"`)`

You can see the file is download in the directory:

[image]

However, when I deploy app using shiny server, the error occurs:

**Shiny server:**

```
Error in curl_download: Failed to open file /srv/shiny-server/PowerSeq_app/www/reviews2.csv.
```

I assumed this is file path issue, I also turned to this [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/229848967-Why-does-my-app-work-locally-but-not-on-shinyapps-io-), but I still cannot get it resolved. Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I realized it's user privilege issue, we have to change the privilege of user "shiny":

```
groupadd shiny-apps
usermod -aG shiny-apps shiny
chown -R shiny:shiny-apps /srv/shiny-server
chmod g+w /srv/shiny-server
chmod g+s /srv/shiny-server
```

[image]